# Caching mp3 files on windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

Suppose I have an app that can play MP3 files over the internet. Is it possible to automatically cache them as they get downloaded, just like browsers do it?

Comment: Maybe you can use a background downloader and store them in your application local or temporary folder?

Comment: @Jogy I can but that's an ugly workaround. I wonder if there's any built-in capabilities for truly automatic caching available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no any built in capabilities in WP8/8.1 API that can do this. The only way to do this is to download the mp3 to the `IsolatedStorage` and the use it.

If you want you can map the mp3 to the downloaded link by creating your own code in case you want the cache like functionality when offline. In the question there is not much information to go around but the final answer is, no there is not such capability as of now.

Comment: Can you plz explain with detail coding, how to get mp3 from web and store in cache to use it offline.